# CSS DIV Classes with a "Greater than or Less than" indicator

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use div classes for a > or < sign in CSS?

the problem I have is with the div in css, that I want to rename to use it for only one div and not global like it does now. E.g.: div into ".box { }" and ".box > div { }" I dont know how the greater than works with these changes.

The code iam working with:

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
}

div > div {
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}

.under {
    background: yellow;
    top: 0px;
}

.top {
    background: #008285;
    bottom: -50px;
    top: 330px;
}

.top:hover {
    background: #008285;
    bottom: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
<div class="under"><img src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/244xp91.jpg" alt="test"></div>
<div class="top">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. aurabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui.
</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yr8zkqvd/2/

Comment: What do you mean by... "use"?

Comment: None of your class names include either of those characters. I've no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve here. Try elaborating.

Comment: @JanneKlouman Iam sorry. What iam trying to change is that the main div overlapping under and top is reffering to this css part div and div > div. I want to change this into a class like: <div class=name> and have this set in the css, but the div > div must also change with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking if you can substitute this css rule

```
div > div {
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

for something more precise.

Yes, you can

Give your outer div a class, perhaps '.wrapper` and you can do this

```
.wrapper > .top {
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

By the way, the wrapper should have `position:relative`

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yr8zkqvd/8/)

In fact, however, in this single instance, you don't actually need to do that at all

[**Reduced CSS JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yr8zkqvd/11/)

Comment: This makes sense to me now :) thank you for learning me this! I was struggling with it for a while...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem has anything to do with the `>`.  It looks like you're trying to make a `div` 70px high, and put your image inside.  The problem is that a `div` has the `overflow` style set to `visible` by default, which means that when the image overflows the `div`, the rest of it will still be visible.  You need to add `overflow: hidden` to your style to prevent this.

```
div > div {
  height: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yr8zkqvd/3/)

Comment: I thank you but that part was already working :) since it expands when you hover over it. But the problem I have is with the div in css, that I want to rename to use it for only one div and not global like it does now. E.g.: div into ".box { }" and ".box > div { }" I dont know how the greater than works with these changes.

Comment: @user3615331:  Makes a little more sense.  I suggest adding that explanation to your original question, since I don't think anyone actually understood what you were asking.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i edited my original post and got my answer :D